# 504 Deadline Exceeded running simple python example

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am receiving a 504 Deadline Exceeded error trying to run a simple python script to add a document to Firestore.

```
from firebase_admin import firestore, credentials

cred = credentials.Certificate("<path to service account>")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
print("initialized firebase successfully")

product_dict={
  'test1': 'test',
  'test2': 'test2'
}
firestore_client = firestore.client()
doc_ref = firestore_client.collection('products').document('test')
doc_ref.set(product_dict)
```

Output:

```
intialized firebase successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    doc_ref.set(product_dict)
  File "/Users/.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/document.py", line 234, in set
    write_results = batch.commit()
  File "/Users/.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/batch.py", line 147, in commit
    metadata=self._client._rpc_metadata,
  File "/Users/.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/gapic/firestore_client.py", line 1042, in commit
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "/Users/.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 273, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/Users/.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 182, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/Users/.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "/Users/.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 737, in raise_from
    raise value
google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded
```

I've tried using Pipenv with Python 3.7, and virtualenv with python 2, same results.

Running from terminal on macOS Mojave 10.14.3